# Injecting beans in an order

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring and here is my use case in a standalone java application.

Have an entry point that needs to create 4 services : s1, s2,s3 and s4 in that order.

S1 init properties are currently in a property file. S1 will populate the properties needed to create S2, s3 and s4.

Wondering how I can leverage Spring to do this. Overall objective is to have different implementation for these services.

Thanks for your help,
Regards
cabear

Comment: Why do your beans have to be initialized in order? That's usually a indicator that something is weird. If there are dependencies, you don't have to worry about the order, spring handles that (you just can't have circular dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

ou can use @DependsOn("beanName") annotation (or depends-on="beanName" in XML).

```
@Component
public class S2{

    @Autowired
    public S1 s1;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
      //read data from s1
    }

}

Do the same for s3 and s4
```

Comment: Thanks, how to provide the parameters from s1 to s2

Answer (score 0):

In order to load properties that are used for other beans I recommend to use a property-placeholder.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />
<bean id="someBean" class="...">
    <property name="myProperty" value="${keyOfProperty}" />
</bean>
```

After a quick google I found [this blog post](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/#xml) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.. in my usecase, the properties of s1 comes from a file.. then when s1 is initiaized, it read an external system to get more properties that will be used to initialize s2 and so on.. any pointers to pass the properties from s1 to s2 creation using Spring..

Comment: you can also use it for files on the file system with `<context:property-placeholder location="file:/folder/myPropertyFile.properties" />`

Comment: If the services exist only for loading properties then you could write your own property placeholder by subclassing `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` . Otherwise you could Autowire your Services and provide methods for retrieving the properties which are loaded on demand. The values can then be cached.